# Quantize a real-valued function?

Tags: functions, function-construction

I'm wondering if there's a built-in way in Mathematica to take a function whose output values are continuous, and quantize it to produce a step function.  For example, I have the function

```
f[x_, n_, h_] := ArcTan[(n x)/h]*180/Pi - ArcTan[((n - 1) x)/h]*180/Pi
```

which I would like to digitize so that it takes on values in the set `{0, 5, ... , 25}`.  I've done some searching but can't find a good way to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`Round`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Round.html).  The second argument of `Round` is the quantization step.

Examples:

```
Plot[
 Round[Sin[x], 0.2],
 {x, 0, 2 Pi}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[
 Round[Sin[x], 0.2],
 {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]